# in React, "history.push('/')" is not working in some component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to make re-directing function from the QnaNew.js.

```
  onSubmit = (formProps) => {
    this.props.createPost(formProps, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/qna');
    });
  };
```

I want to make it When I send post req then redirect to '/qna'.
Strangely, the redirect is working in Login.js, Join.js page.

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

src - index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import history from './history';

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {
    auth: { authenticated: localStorage.getItem('token') },
  },
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

QnANew.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
//import { createPost } from '../../actions'



class QnANew extends Component {
  renderInput({ input, label, meta }) {
    return (
      <div className="qnaTitle">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <input {...input} />
        <div>{meta.error}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderEditor({ input, label }) {
    return (
      <div className="qnaContent">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <CKEditor
          data={input.value}
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            return input.onChange(editor.getData());
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmit = (formProps) => {
    this.props.createPost(formProps, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/qna');
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="QnaNew">
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="ui form">
          <fieldset>
            <Field name="title" type="text" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Title" autoComplete="none" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <Field name="content" type="text" component={this.renderEditor} label="Enter Description" autoComplete="none" />
          </fieldset>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}





const validate = (formValues) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!formValues.title) {
    errors.title = 'You must enter a title';
  }

  return errors;
}


const formWrapped = reduxForm({ form: 'QnANew', validate })(QnANew);

export default compose(connect(null, actions))(formWrapped);
```

actions - index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../history';
import qna from '../apis/qna';
import { AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, CREATE_QNA, FETCH_QNA, FETCH_QNAS, EDIT_QNA, DELETE_QNA } from './types';

export const join = (formProps, callback) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/join', formProps);
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER, payload: response.data.token });
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: 'Email in use'});
  }
}


export const login = (formProps) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', formProps);
    
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER, payload: response.data.token });
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
    history.push('/'); 
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: 'Invalid login credentials' });
  }
};


export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
  return {
    type: AUTH_USER,
    payload: ''
  };
}


export const createPost = (formProps) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await qna.post('/qnanew', { ...formProps });
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_QNA, payload: response.data });
  history.push('/qna');
};

export const fetchPost = (id) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await qna.get(`/qna/${id}`);
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_QNA, payload: response.data });
};


// Post List
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await qna.get('/qna');
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_QNAS, payload: response.data });
};

export const editPost = (id, formValues) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await qna.put(`/qna/${id}`, formValues);
  dispatch({ type: EDIT_QNA, payload: response.data });
};

export const deletePost = (id) => async dispatch => {
  await qna.delete(`/qna/${id}`);
  dispatch({ type: DELETE_QNA, payload: id });
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import './Login.scss';

class Login extends Component {
  onSubmit = (formProps) => {
    this.props.login(formProps, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="Join">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>Login page</p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="JoinForm">
          <fieldset>
            <label>Email</label>
            <Field name="email" type="text" component="input" autoComplete="none" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <label>Password</label>
            <Field name="password" type="password" component="input" autoComplete="none" />
          </fieldset>
          <div>{this.props.errorMessage}</div>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage };
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, actions), reduxForm({ form: 'login' }))(Login);
```

Comment: `onSubmit` will continue to do it's default action, and this involves loading the current page, so your history is likely working, but the form submit then runs.   so try -> `formProps.preventDefault()` inside your `onSubmit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this:

```
this.props.history.push('/');
this.props.history.go('/');
```

or:

```
window.location.href = "/";
```